Flutter app_links Universal deep links not returning in URI stream listen. Not navigating to route in app only opens to dashboard
I have this working in android, it navigates to the page deep in the app but still running into issues on ios. I want to navigate to certain routes in my app with a link, it opens up my app in ios when clicking on the link but fails to navigate to the route I have defined, it doesn't even return anything in the listen on flutter but it is catching the url since debug output in the AppDelegate outputs the correct url that I am clicking. I just really have no idea what I am missing at this point.
Using this package for deep links: https://pub.dev/packages/app_links
My link is like https://mydomain/pub-crawl/{unique-id}
I have added my domain to the associated domains as applinks:mydomain and have set FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled in Info.plist to false and have tried with true but results are the same.
This is my controller that initializes it, I call the handleIncomingLinks function a bit later in the setupInitialStuff function at the end so I can do initial user setup if it's a cold boot.
class SplashController extends GetxController {
  late final AppLinks appLinks;
  StreamSubscription? streamSub;

  @override
  void onReady() async {
    appLinks = AppLinks();
    await setupInitialStuff();
    super.onReady();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    streamSub?.cancel();  // Clean up the stream subscription
    super.onClose();
  }

  Future<void> handleIncomingLinks() async {
    // Listen for deep links while the app is running
    
    streamSub = appLinks.uriLinkStream.listen((Uri? uri) {
      if (uri != null) {
        deepLinkNavigation(uri);
      }
    }, onError: (err) {
      print('Failed to receive deep link: $err');
    });
  }



  Future<void> deepLinkNavigation(Uri uri) async {

    // Extract the first segment to determine the prefix (e.g., "pub-crawl" or "business")
    final prefix = uri.pathSegments.first;
    final uniqname = uri.pathSegments.last;

    // Add a small delay to ensure the home screen is visible first
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));

    if (prefix == "pub-crawl") {
      await MyApplication.pubCrawlController.goToPubCrawlDeepLink(uniqname);
    } else if (prefix == "business") {
      await MyApplication.businessController.goToBusinessDeepLink(uniqname);
    } else {
      // Handle unexpected prefixes or add a fallback
      print('Unknown prefix: $prefix');
    }
  }
  
  Future<void> setupInitialStuff() async {
    //do stuff at app start
    await handleIncomingLinks();
  }
}


My AppDelegate.swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import app_links

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

    // Retrieve the link from parameters
    if let url = AppLinks.shared.getLink(launchOptions: launchOptions) {
      // We have a link, propagate it to your Flutter app or not
      AppLinks.shared.handleLink(url: url)
      return true // Returning true will stop the propagation to other packages
    }

    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }



}

My apple-app-site-association which is served as json at my domain/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "MyTeamId.com.bundle.identifier",
        "paths": ["/pub-crawl/*", "/business/*"]
      }
    ]
  }
}


This is not the ideal solution since I would prefer to simply use the package but I have set it up to use MethodChannels specifically for ios instead but continue using the package for android. Works fine for me so whatever but still not sure why the package isn't working.
AppDelegate.swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import app_links

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  
  var methodChannel: FlutterMethodChannel?

  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

    // Set up method channel for deep links
    if let controller = window?.rootViewController as? FlutterViewController {
      methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "my.bundle.identifier/deeplink", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
    }

    // Handle deep link if app is launched with a URL
    if let url = AppLinks.shared.getLink(launchOptions: launchOptions) {
      sendDeepLinkToFlutter(url: url)
      return true
    }

    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

  // Handle Universal Links when the app is already running
  override func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
      // Pass the URL to Flutter
      sendDeepLinkToFlutter(url: incomingURL)
    }
    return true
  }

  // Custom method to send the URL to Flutter using a platform channel
  private func sendDeepLinkToFlutter(url: URL) {
    methodChannel?.invokeMethod("onDeepLink", arguments: url.absoluteString)
  }
}


My controller

class SplashController extends GetxController {
  late final AppLinks appLinks;
  StreamSubscription? streamSub;
  static const platform = MethodChannel('my.bundle.identifier/deeplink');

  @override
  void onReady() async {
    appLinks = AppLinks();
    await setupInitialStuff();
    super.onReady();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    streamSub?.cancel();  // Clean up the stream subscription
    super.onClose();
  }


  Future<void> handleIncomingLinks() async {
    streamSub = appLinks.uriLinkStream.listen((Uri? uri) {
      if (uri != null) {
        deepLinkNavigation(uri);
      } else {
        print('No URI received.');
      }
    }, onError: (err) {
      print('Failed to receive deep link: $err');
    });
  }

  // Method to handle incoming links via Method Channel for iOS
  void handleMethodChannelForIOS() {
    platform.setMethodCallHandler((MethodCall call) async {
      if (call.method == 'onDeepLink') {
        final String? url = call.arguments;
        if (url != null) {
          Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
          print('Received deep link from iOS: $uri');
          deepLinkNavigation(uri);
        }
      }
    });
  }


  Future<void> deepLinkNavigation(Uri uri) async {
    final prefix = uri.pathSegments.first;
    final uniqname = uri.pathSegments.last;

    if (prefix == "pub-crawl") {
      await MyApplication.pubCrawlController.goToPubCrawlDeepLink(uniqname);
    } else if (prefix == "business") {
      await MyApplication.businessController.goToBusinessDeepLink(uniqname);
    } else {
      print('Unknown prefix: $prefix');
    }
  }

  Future<void> setupInitialStuff() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
        handleMethodChannelForIOS();
      } else {
        handleIncomingLinks();
      }
  }

}

